# Unable to retrieve a value from JSON, getting 'Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.' exception

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a following JSON sample

```
     "object_properties":{
        "has_related":[
           {
              "id":"id1",
              "label":"label1"
           },
           {
              "id":"id2",
              "label":"label2"
           },
           {
              "id":"id3",
              "label":"label3"
           }
        ],
        "member_of":[
           {
              "id":"id4",
              "label":"label4"
           }
        ],
        "is_top_concept_in_scheme":[
           {
              "id":"id5",
              "label":"label5"
           }
        ],
        "has_broader":[
           {
              "id":"id6",
              "label":"label6"
           }
        ]
     }
```

I am trying to get ID and Label from 'member_of' property using the following code

```
        var objectPropertiesParent = parent["object_properties"];
        if (objectPropertiesParent != null)
        {
            MemberOfConceptObjectId = string.Empty;
            MemberOfConceptObjectLabel = string.Empty;
            var MemberOfConceptObject = objectPropertiesParent.Value<Array>("member_of");
            if (MemberOfConceptObject != null)
            {
                MemberOfConceptObjectId = token.Value<JArray>("object_properties").Values<JArray>("member_of").FirstOrDefault().Values<string>("id").FirstOrDefault();
                MemberOfConceptObjectLabel = token.Value<JArray>("object_properties").Values<JArray>("member_of").FirstOrDefault().Values<string>("label").FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

However, I get the 'Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.' where trying to set the MemberOfConceptObject variable (var MemberOfConceptObject = objectPropertiesParent.Value("member_of"); line)

When I use the following line of code

```
MemberOfConceptObjectId = token.Values<JToken>("object_properties").Values<string>("member_of").FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the following exception : 'Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.'

Please let me know how I should properly and cleanly retrieve ID and Label of member_of property

Thank you very much for the assistance

Comment: That's because it isn't an array.

Comment: Why aren't you just parsing to a class instead of doing all that manual, extremely inefficient code?

Comment: I am taking over someone else's code. The initial JSON file was modified, I am trying to adjust the code accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me

```
        var MemberOfConceptObject = parent["object_properties"]["member_of"];
        if (MemberOfConceptObject != null)
        {
            MemberOfConceptObjectId = MemberOfConceptObject[0]["id"].ToString();
            MemberOfConceptObjectLabel = MemberOfConceptObject[0]["label"].ToString();
        }
```